# cannot change list attribute of current_user in flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a cart for my website. Here is my `User` class:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text)
    roles = db.Column(db.String(length=25))
    stall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stalls.stall_id'), nullable=True)
    cart = []

    def __init__(self, user_id, password, role):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.password = password
        self.roles = role

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id
```

The user can add items to the cart, I am using `UserMixin` and `current_user` to access the cart of the user. Everything works fine here.

```
@app.route('/add-to-cart/<int:picked_dish_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_to_cart(picked_dish_id):
    dish = Dish.query.filter_by(dish_id=picked_dish_id).first()
    current_user.cart.append(dish)
    print(current_user.cart)
    return render_template('add_to_cart.html', dish=dish)
```

But I have problems with deleting the item from the cart, here is my function

```
@app.route('/delete-from-cart/<int:dish_id>')
@login_required
def delete_from_cart(dish_id):
    print(current_user.cart)
    dishes = current_user.cart
    current_user.cart = [dish for dish in dishes if dish.dish_id != int(dish_id)]
    print("Cart after deleting ", end='')
    print(current_user.cart)
    return redirect(url_for('checkout'))
```

After this function is called I am rendering the checkout page again to update the changes

```
@app.route('/checkout')
@login_required
def checkout():
    print("Cart in checkout: ", end='')
    print(current_user.cart)
    return render_template('checkout.html', cart=current_user.cart)
```

So when I am pressing delete button in my front-end firstly `delete_from_cart` function and after that it redirects user to `checkout` page to update the changes.

So here is the output of this two functions when I am trying to delete the item from the cart

```
[<Dish 1>, <Dish 4>]
Cart after deleting [<Dish 4>]
Cart in checkout: [<Dish 1>, <Dish 4>]
```

As you can see the function actually deletes the item from the cart and in function `delete_from_cart` `current_user.cart` list is different, but when it redirects to the checkout page the changes disappear.

Comment: Did you commit your changes? I.e. with db.session.commit()

Comment: No, as I dont have this array in the database, it just a normal python array

Comment: Whenever you call current_user your identifier is used to get the user object from the DB. You cant  add and share an attribute between routes , without committing your changes. Maybe using cookies is an option for you?

Comment: I am really confused now, how come that I can append items in the current_user.cart without commiting it, but I am not able to delete items from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know but `.remove()` function works completely fine and now I can remove items from the cart now

```
@app.route('/delete-from-cart/<int:dish_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_from_cart(dish_id):
    for dish in current_user.cart:
        if dish.dish_id == dish_id:
            current_dish = dish
    current_user.cart.remove(current_dish)
    return redirect(url_for('checkout'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).